# Why does this cube look this way and why can't I scale it correctly?

Tags: modeling, objects, transforms

[image: Cube]Doing a Blender tutorial.  Instructor wanted the viewer to create a cube to use as a cutter.  Took a lot of positioning to get it into the correct location.  So I thought I had a better idea.  Duplicated the object that the arrow points at and made it it's own object.  Removed all modifiers, parenting, eliminated the curved section, and ended up with just a plain at the correct angle etc.  Then extruded it to make a cube.  Question - Why is the cube shaded like this?  Also, notice the 3D cursor.  I can't scale it along it's xzy.  I've tried going from global, to local, to normal with no luck.  Also scale XX doesn't seem to work.  Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please save your image directly into the question rather than just adding an external link to it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post.  That image doesn't really help anyway as you haven't provided a link to the tutorial and we'd really need to see your Blend file which you can share via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there.